# Finding the interval containing the point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I am supposed to find the interval containing point b, such as functional values of points have difference from value g(b) by a maximum of ε.

$$g(b)=a^{2}, b=-3, \varepsilon =\frac{2}{11}$$.

I tried to do it from definition:

$$-3-\delta < x<-3+\delta\Leftrightarrow 9-\frac{2}{11}< a^{2}<9+\frac{2}{11}\Leftrightarrow \frac{97}{11}< a^{2}<\frac{101}{11}   $$
and I do not know what to do next, or if I am right.

Can anyone help me?